# including < > letters is missing

Tags: asp.net

IN database I have a data is  `P13.<Debit Note>結轉傳票`

Then I use treeview to show the menu.

It become `P13.結轉傳票`。

letters in <> is missing.

I Know <> is Special characters in web.

Anyone know why? How to fix?

Comment: You can encode characters

Comment: I'd guess the browser is seeing `P13.<Debit Note>結轉傳票` as a block of HTML and ignores `<Debit Note>` as an unknown HTML tag. You'll probably need to HTML Escape the angle brackets so the rendered string is `P13.&lt;Debit Note&gt;結轉傳票` which the browser will render as you expected.